# Ist "Er hat mit dir einen Termin" gutes Deutsch?

Tags: sentence-structure, dative, accusative

I know that dative comes first (besides when there is a personal pronoun which is in the accusative) but -

*Er hat einen Termin mit dir* sounds better to my ears.

Which is right? or both work? If the latter works, how come the accusative comes before the dative object (which in this case is also a personal pronoun)?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. *Er hat einen Termin mit dir* is more common. *Er hat mit dir einen Termin* puts some emphasis on *mit dir*.

*Mit dir* is not an ordinary dative object but a prepositonal object. Prepositional objects usually go after other (non-prepositional) objects but they can placed rather freely, especially for emphasis.

Comment: Thanks! So if so - *Ich mochte einen Kuchen mit dir essen* also works? Or another example - *Ich esse einen Kuchen mit dir* here it sounds wrong accusative before dative

Comment: It's not dative before accusative. It's dative object before accusative object. This isn't a dative object, but a prepositional object with a preposition which requires the dative.

Comment: @Janka Can you give more examples where a prepositional dative object follows the accusative object?

Comment: Pretty much always when you have a preposition which requires the dative. Here's an example which has prepositional objects with dative before and after the accusative object: *Sie legte an diesem Tag den Weg zur Arbeit mit dem Bus zurück.* The only fixed object order is *den Weg zur Arbeit*. That's fixed because *zu* is a very "clinging" preposition, even more clinging than *mit*.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically both variants are fine. *Einen Termin haben* is somewhat formal, however, and applies to dentist, doctor, car workshop and similar occasions. If you just have an appointment with your friend

> Er ist mit dir verabredet

would be a better match. This also avoids the "weak" verb *haben*, which is too universal and therefore won't be overly appreciated by German teachers.